# How to create an image button in tkinter? and how to put into another interface?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, button, widget

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

def save():
     editor = Tk()

     img= Image.open('images/save.png')
     fixed= ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    btn_save_editor = Button(editor, image=fixed)
    btn_save_editor.place(x=30, y=80, height=20)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `Toplevel` (not `Tk`) for windows other than the root. Also, you haven't called the `save()` function.

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

From another interface, if you mean another window, then you should use a TopLevel widget, not TK

```
from tkinter import * 
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

def save(): 
    editor = Toplevel()
    editor.geometry("500x500") # you can change it

    img = Image.open('images/save.png')
    fixed= ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    btn_save_editor = Button(editor, image=fixed)
    btn_save_editor.place(x=30, y=80, height=20)

save()

root.mainloop()
```